# SharedPreferences with a Save Button

Tags: android

I am new to the Android/Java development, please go easy on me.

The app is relatively simple, It's just a connection to a MSQL Database 
For each user the connection settings will be different, so I created a new Activity for settings. 
I think I am storing the values from the Activity_Settings.xml correctly and storing them to the SharedPreferences.
But I cannot understand how to create a lister to commit the changes.

The ultimate goal would be entering the Settings activity would show the EditText filled with the values from SharedPreferences. And saving and exiting would write them back to SharedPreferences.

Here is what I have for the Activity, If someone could point me in the right direction, I have checked https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences and its confusing me more

Settings.Java

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring layout button, edit texts
    EditText ServerName,ServerPort,DatabaseName,ServerPath;
    // End Declaring layout button, edit texts

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)     //Creating Instance for storing data
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);    // Fetch from Activity_Settings

        // Getting values from any button or text fields
        ServerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerName);
        ServerPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerPort);
        DatabaseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DBName);
        ServerPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerPath);
        // End Getting values from any button or text fields


        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    //    editor.putString("ServerName","192.168.1.75");
    //    editor.putInt("ServerPort",1433);
    //    editor.putString("DBName","OpenXpos");
    //    editor.putString("ServerPath","\\\\/Server01\\/OpenXpos\\/");

        editor.putString("ServerName", String.valueOf(ServerName));
        editor.putString("ServerPort", String.valueOf(ServerPort));
        editor.putString("DBName", String.valueOf(DatabaseName));
        editor.putString("ServerPath", String.valueOf(ServerPath));


        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Activity_Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.openretail.stocktake.Settings">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:text="Save Exit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="Server Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Server Port"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Database Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Server Path"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ServerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="192.168.X.X"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ServerPort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Default:1433"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ServerName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DBName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="OpenXpos"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ServerPort" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ServerPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="\\\\Server01\\OpenXpos\\"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DBName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as following, first you assign a click listener using `setOnClickListener()` on the button object and then in `onCreate()` load the data from shared preference. and if user clicks the button then he will get notified in button click listener callback where the data will saved. Code below gives the general idea on how to do so.

```
 public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Declaring layout button, edit texts
        EditText serverName,serverPort,databaseName,serverPath;
        // End Declaring layout button, edit texts
        Button saveButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)     //Creating Instance for storing data
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);    // Fetch from Activity_Settings

            // Getting values from any button or text fields
            serverName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerName);
            serverPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerPort);
            databaseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DBName);
            serverPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ServerPath);

            //get the shared preference instance
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. save);
            // End Getting values from any button or text fields
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //here save the data
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
         editor.putString("server_name",serverName.getText().toString());
         editor.putString("server_port",serverPort.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("database_name",databaseName.getText().toString());
         editor.putString("server_path",serverPath.getText().toString());
         editor.commit();
               }
            });

         //set the default values saved on load
        serverName.setText(preferences.getString("server_name",""));
        serverPort.setText(preferences.getString("server_port",""));
        databaseName.setText(preferences.getString("database_name",""));
        serverPath.setText(preferences.getString("server_path",""));
        }
    }
```

Note: Also don't assign cap naming to instance variables. Use camelCase always

Comment: This makes much more sense now Thank you. Am curious of two things. Why the use of camelCase? (I come from PHP so a steep learning curve) 
If i want main activity to pickup these variables, Do i have to do anything special like make them Public / Global? Or do i just load the SharedPref in the main activity too? or make use of an Intent?

Comment: I got this working, Although i suspect its not the right way nor clean way, 
I called back:         final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 in Main Activity: Defined each variable as so:
        String serverName = preferences.getString("server_name", "");
And bundled it together like so: 
        db = String.format("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://%s:%s/%s", serverName, serverPort, databaseName) ;

Answer (score 1):

you need to get text value from edit-text and commit to

```
editor.putString("server_name",serverName.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("server_port",serverPort.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("database_name",databaseName.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("server_path",serverPath.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, This explains why it was not saving correctly